# Is it possible to run iOS simulator on a Mac without Xcode installed?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ios4, ios-simulator

There are a few questions relating to this topic but nothing quite the same when it comes down to the details:

We would like to use the iOS Simulator without installing the rest of XCode on a macbook. It is an in-house laptop, and will be used by employees, but not engineers.

We already know how to run applications on the simulator without the source code and compiling required, but it would be nice to be able to install a 100MB app and application support that can run our in-house distribution app as opposed to a 2.4GB XCode installation. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Simulator app requires several other large directories from the Xcode distribution in order to work at all.  The only official way to install all of those properly is to install the entire SDK from the dmg.  Then you can experiment with deleting the hopefully "unneeded" directories.  Be prepared to start over if you delete something that the Simulator requires.

Comment: Yes this sounds like the only option I came up with as well. I was hoping there was a simpler solution. Thanks!

Comment: Could there be any way to compile a version of the Simulator app and statically link in all dependencies, so that it would run without the rest of Xcode?

Comment: Anyone care to post the "unneeded directories" they successfully deleted in this case? :)

Answer (score 3):

You would have to extract the Simulator pkg from the Xcode DMG. The only thing is that the Simulator depends on having an SDK installed, that way it knows which iOS to run the app in.

Answer (score 0):

Simulators are not available as separate/stand alone downloads.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac then the best way is to right-click the Xcode app in your finder applications folder and select Package Contents. Delete all folders except the 'Developer' folder and drag this 'Developer' folder out of Xcode. Now you will be able to access Simulator as well as Xcode Server Builder without the rest of Xcode through the launcher. After dragging the folder out of the contents of Xcode, you can safely delete Xcode.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't download ios simulator stand-alone

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers.